# Possible EventEmmiter memory leak sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've installed sails.js and add some lines of code ... and now I'm getting this error messages. What's wrong?

```
error: Grunt :: (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 change listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
error: Grunt :: Trace
    at StatWatcher.addListener (events.js:239:17)
    at Object.fs.watchFile (fs.js:1424:8)
    at Gaze._pollFile (/home/ketys/batn/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:329:10)
    at /home/ketys/batn/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:411:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /home/ketys/batn/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:409:11
    at iterate (/home/ketys/batn/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)
    at /home/ketys/batn/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:61:11
    at /home/ketys/batn/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:420:5
    at iterate (/home/ketys/batn/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? This error doesn't appear on a vanilla install of sails.